# split list of tuples in lists of list of tuples

Tags: python, list, split, grouping

I have a list of tuples like:

```
[(1,a),(2,b), (1, e), (3, b), (2,c), (4,d), (1, b), (0,b), (6, a), (8, e)]
```

I want to split it into list of lists at every "b"

```
[[(1,a),(2,b)], [(1, e), (3, b)], [(2,c), (4,d), (1, b)], [(0,b)], [(6, a), (8, e)]]
```

is there any pythonic way to do this?

Comment: I'd claim that a straight-forward `for` loop here is pythonic as the intention might not be clear if you mangle this into some comprehension-generator-thingy. Explicit is better then implicit.

Comment: Do the b's always occur uniformly like they do here?

Comment: no. they dont. I updated the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_list = [(1, "a"),(2, "b"), (1, "e"), (3, "b"), (2, "c"), (1, "b"), (0, "b")]
result, temp = [], []

for item in my_list:
    temp.append(item)
    if item[1] == 'b':
        result.append(temp)
        temp = []

if len(temp) > 0:
    result.append(temp)

print result
# [[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')], [(1, 'e'), (3, 'b')], [(2, 'c'), (1, 'b')], [(0, 'b')]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `yield`.

```
def get_groups(lst):
    t = []
    for i in lst:
        t.append(i)
        if i[1] == 'b':
            yield t
            t = []
    if t:
        yield t

my_list = [(1,a),(2,b), (1, e), (3, b), (2,c), (1, b), (0,b)]
groups = list(get_groups(my_list))
```

Comment: Does not work if the last element does not end with `b`. You should check if `t` contains elements and yield it in this case at the end of your function.

Comment: What should do if the last one doesnt end in 'b', include it or not?

Comment: It should be included

Comment: That is not nice. Changing the question afterwards.

Comment: @Avempace I added one more tuple to make it clear that even if it doesnt end in "b", it should return the full list as a sublist

Comment: Thanks! Changed the answer for that. I was experimenting anyway. I would not do that way in production as Janyanth said

Comment: The code fails for huge lists with no "b". So I accepted the answer by @thefourtheye although I like generators

Comment: @AbhishekThakur: we both have the same solution except that this uses a generator. Why would this fail for 'huge lists'?

Comment: Sorry. Its not huge lists. It produces repetitions and the generated list becomes "huge"

Answer (score 1):

My solution, directly in the python console:

```
>>> l = [(1,'a'),(2,'b'), (1, 'e'), (3, 'b'), (2,'c'), (1, 'b'), (0,'b')]
>>> b = [-1] + [x for x, y in enumerate(l) if y[1] == 'b' or x == len(l)-1]
>>> u = zip(b,b[1:])
>>> m = [l[x[0]+1:x[1]+1] for x in u]
>>> m
[[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')], [(1, 'e'), (3, 'b')], [(2, 'c'), (1, 'b')], [(0, 'b')]]
```

**b** is the indices of the tuples with 'b', starting by -1.

```
[-1, 1, 3, 5, 6]
```

**u** is tuples of indices of the sublist that we will create:

```
[(-1, 1), (1, 3), (3, 5), (5, 6)]
```

And for the case not ending in a tuple with 'b':

```
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (1, 'e'), (3, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (1, 'b'), (0, 'b'), (6, 'a'), (8, 'e')]
```

gives:

```
[[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')], [(1, 'e'), (3, 'b')], [(2, 'c'), (1, 'b')], [(0, 'b')], [(6, 'a'), (8, 'e')]]
```

Comment: This is less intuitive *and* less efficient than a simple for loop.

Comment: The questions says "is there any pythonic way to do this?". Only showing other alternatives.

Comment: Intuitiveness is a big part of 'pythonic'.

Comment: This fails if last item doesn't contain `'b'`.

Comment: What should it give? I tried, and split in blocks ending by the tuple with the b. Are you assuming something not specify in the question?

Comment: fixed now, by adding x == len(l)-1

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
xs = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (1, 'e'), (3, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (1, 'b'), (0, 'b'), (6, 'a'), (8, 'e')]

result = [[]]
for x in xs:
  result[0].append(x)
  if x[1] == 'b':
    result.insert(0, [])
result.reverse()
```

Answer (score 1):

A pure iterator solution:

```
def get_groups(lst):
    i = iter(lst)
    def row(x):
        while True:
            yield x
            if x[1] == 'b':
                return
            x = next(i)

    for x in i:
        yield row(x)

for r in get_groups(data):
    print list(r)
```